# how can i install free local mailserver on windows?

Tags: php, smtp

I've been trying to send email via php **mail()** function and it gives me this error line : *mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()*.
I searched a lot for the solution but I always end up in a closed road.

So if someone could help me getting the smtp mailserver I will be so thankful for that , and correct me if I was wrong about any information.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a local SMTP server? If you don't know, the answer is probably no. Are you on a local development environment or a host? If local, I generally wouldn't recommend installing one.

Comment: @ChrisHaas **No** i don't have a local STMP server, and **Yes** i am on a local development environment , so what do you recommend me to do in this case so i can use the mail function ? And thanks for your comment.

Comment: https://medium.com/@coffmans/setup-your-own-simple-smtp-server-how-to-c9159cfc7934

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-smtp-server-computer-51563.html

Comment: The above is just the result of some trivial googling. There are more results available. I don't think you really need us to do that kind of research for you though

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your time. Actually i was just discovering the hmailserver right now and i think it is exactly what i need. But that article of yours will help for sure !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. php version - 7.4.16
2. xampp version - 3.2.4
3. Windows 7 64-bit

---

**Configure *php.ini* file -**

file path - `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

in `php.ini` file find `[mail function]` and do below changes -

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

---

**Configure *sendmail.ini* file -**

file path - `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`

> Note : if you don't have sendmail file/folder, please follow download and setup process below.

in `sendmail.ini` file do below changes -

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

> Now Restart the server (Apache) using the XAMMP so the changes take
> effect.

> Note : If `;` (semi colon) exists at the starting of mentioned lines, Remove them

---

**Configure *Google Account* -**

Turn on "Less secure app access" from google account 'security' tab.

e.g. -

[image: Less-secure-app-access]

Ref url - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

---

**Steps to download and setup sendmail package -**

Step 1 - Download zip file from https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/

Step 2 - Extract all files within 'sendmail' folder and paste it on 'xampp' folder.

e.g. -

[image: sendmail-path]

---

Now all set!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

This whole method of sending mail is perfectly working in my localhost.

[image: SMTP-mail]